# Is there a way for the GWT Maven Plugin to generate I18N message interfaces which return SafeHtml?

Tags: gwt, maven, internationalization

For a GWT project, if you configure the pom to generate your I18N Message bundles, the generated interfaces all return String.

I was wondering if there was a way to have the Message bundle interfaces generated s.t. some or all of the methods return SafeHtml.

I'm not sure how you would selectively decide which messages return String and which return SafeHtml (perhaps through some kind of markup in the .properties file).

Comment: Right now, it seems like this isn't possible. If that is the case, then it seems the only option is to split the .properties into two seperate files; one which is generated, and one which contains the SafeHtml messages (in a XssSafeMessages.properties file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite being bound to a phase by default, `gwt:i18n` shouldn't be used during your build in 99.9% of the time.

`gwt:i18n` is great to bootstrap an interface from an existing properties file but it falls short to supporting all the great features of GWT I18N: non-String constants, non-String message parameters, plurals and other alternate messages, and `SafeHtml`.

My advice: ditch `gwt:i18n`.

Comment: Yeah. The small payoff of not having to maintain the interface vs having all the things you mentioned is not worth it. But what strikes me as funny is that i18n message generation is part of the GWT maven archetype. Are you saying that gwt:i18n is a bad choice all around, or are you suggesting that it is a poor choice given the context I've provided?

Comment: It's a bad choice. IMO it should only be a bootstrap tool. I discourage using the gwt-maven-plugin archetype for many reasons, including that one.

Comment: Are you suggesting to write and maintain both the property file and the Messages interface by hand? That's twice the work.

Comment: I suggest replacing one of your properties file with using `@DefaultMessage` on your interface, which also allows you to use non-string arguments and plural rules / select via `@AlternateMessage`. By using `gwt:i18n`, you're losing 90% of the features of GWT I18N.